# Delete only files older than 7 days: -mtime and find

Tags: find

Found a few similar questions but were not quite a match.

I have a directory for backups (sql) and want to delete all files in that directory older then 7 days leaving any sub-directories intact.

This is what I have:

```
find /var/log/mbackups -mtime +7 -type f -delete
```

Is this the proper way to accomplish what I am after?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving any sub-directories intact"? Do you mean "don't delete files from sub-directories" or do you mean "don't delete the sub-directories themselves"?

Comment: Note the gotcha about `-mtime +N`. With GNU find, `-mtime +7` will find files that are at least _eight_ days old.

Comment: @ilkkachu, that's not limited to GNU `find`. It is a POSIX requirement (though IIRC some BSDs are/were not compliant in that regard).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, oh, okay. Should try to remember that for the next time, thankss.

Answer (score 10):

Your command will look at the top level directory `/var/log/mbackups` and also descend into any subdirectories, deleting files that match the seven day criterion. It will not delete the directories themselves.

If you want a command to look at files only in the `/var/log/mbackups` directory, and *not descend into subdirectories*, you need to add that restriction:

```
find /var/log/mbackups -maxdepth 1 -mtime +7 -type f -delete
```

In general you can test the `find` command by replacing the `-delete` action with something innocuous, like `-print` (you need `-depth` here too, as `-delete` implies `-depth`):

```
find /var/log/mbackups -depth -mtime +7 -type f -print
```

Comment: For files older than 7 days, you need `-mtime +6` (or `'(' -mtime 7 -o -mtime +7 ')'`), not `-mtime +7`.

Comment: Also note that `-delete` implies `-depth`. So, when testing with `-print`, it's best to include a `-depth` so you get the same thing as what `-delete` would do (very important if also using `-prune` which is ineffective when combined with `-depth`)

Comment: Note that while `-delete` is a BSD extension, `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension, though these days both are supported by GNU and most BSDs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if you're using a granularity of days, then `+7` will be files that are 8 days or older, which answers the question in the way that I have offered. If you're using a granularity of seconds then your suggestion would be correct. That's the wonder of English language ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

With zsh:

```
rm -f /var/log/mbackups/*(.m+6)
```

same as:

```
rm -f /var/log/mbackups/*(.^m-7)
```

Would remove the regular (with `.`) files that are not hidden and haven't been modified in the last 7 days. Like for `find`'s `-mtime +7`, `m+7` would match on files whose age rounded down to the next integer number of days is strictly greater than 7, so would match on files that are 8 days old or older (a common pitfall when working with `find`).

To also remove old hidden files, add the `D` glob qualifier.

If there's no matching file, you'll get an error message. You can avoid it by adding the `N` glob qualifier (and `rm` will then be called without filename argument, but with `-f`, it should not complain about it).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of rawhide (rh) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

Almost. It's very close. The correct version of your attempt is:

```
find /var/log/mbackups -maxdepth 1 -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

If you find *find*'s `-mtime` predicate argument insufficiently intuitive, you could use *rawhide* (*rh*) instead:

```
rh -UUU -r /var/log/mbackups 'f && old(7*days)'
```

`-UUU` unlinks/removes/deletes matches.

`-r` is like *find*'s `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` and only searches exactly one level below the search path(s), so sub-directories are not searched.

`f` matches regular files.

`old(7*days)` matches things last modified at least 7 days ago.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
find /var/log/mbackups -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Any reason why you would use that instead of the command in the question? Note that the question asks "is this the proper way?", not "are there any other ways?".

Answer (score -4):

Warning: `-delete` is non-standard (nonportable) and risky when using  `gfind`.

Remember that `rm` has some security restrictions, but the `gfind` man page does not mention such a restrictions for `-delete`. I therefore recommend to use the official method:

```
find /var/log/mbackups -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm {} +
```

This is not even slower than the non-standard method using `-delete`.

Comment: `rm` will happily delete a file beginning with `./`, for example `touch xx; rm ./xx`

Comment: `-delete` is from BSD, not GNU and was especially designed to overcome the limitations and security issues of `-exec rm`. Also note that the OP asked files in subdirectories be left alone.